# Getting emails from MySQL and sending emails to them

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm trying to get the emails which have "all" under "selectedoption" column from MySQL database table and then sending emails to them.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

  include("config.php");

  $con = mysql_connect($opt_host, $opt_user, $opt_pw);
  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db_selected = mysql_select_db("databasename_",$con);

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM optins");

  if(mysql_num_rows($selectedoption == "all")
  {
    while($selectedoption_result = mysql_fetch_array($selectedoption))
    { 
      $opt_name = "Name: Advisor\n"
      $opt_header = "From: $MYEMAILADDRESS\n"
      $opt_subject = "Test";
      $opt_email_to = "$email";
      $opt_message = "Hey $name\n"
          . "\n"
          . "Message.\n"
          . "\n"
          . "\n"
          . "Click Here To Unsubscribe.";

      @mail($opt_email_to, $opt_subject ,$opt_message ,$opt_header, $opt_name) ;
    }
  }
  echo("<p align='center'><font face='Arial' size='3' color='#FF0000'>Email Sent Out</font></p>");

?>
```

What is the right way to select a column field from MySQL table and send emails to the recipients associated with that column?

Comment: you're missing a parenthesis in `mysql_num_rows` line. And the parameter is also wrong. Is your table even named `optins`?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite new to PHP please bare with me.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: My PDO knowledge is very limited, I think I'll have to use AWeber now.

Comment: @MattJ The mysqli API is almost identical to the mysql API. Like PDO, it also supports prepared statements. Look, you've even snuck it in there in one instance!

Comment: Your query is failing. You are mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` functions; one of the main reason why your code is failing; they do not mix together. Choose "one" API, not a mix of both.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$mysqli = new mysqli($opt_host, $opt_user, $opt_pw, "databasename_");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM options WHERE selectedoption == 'all'");

$opt_name = "Name: Advisor \n";
$youremail = "foo@bar.com";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $opt_header = "From: " . $opt_name . "<" . $youremail . ">" . "\r\n";
    $opt_subject = "Test";
    $opt_email_to = $row['email_column'];
    $opt_message = "Hey " . $row['name_column'] . "\n"
        . "\n"
        . Message . "\n"
        . "\n"
        . "\n"
        . "Click Here To Unsubscribe.";

    @mail($opt_email_to, $opt_subject, $opt_message, $opt_header) ;
}

echo("<p align='center'><font face='Arial' size='3' color='#FF0000'>Emails Sent Out</font></p>");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $opt_name = "Name: ".$row['name_column']."\n";
        $opt_header = "From: $opt_name <$YOUREMAIL>";
        $opt_subject = "Test";
        $opt_email_to = $row['email_column'];
        $opt_message = "Hey $opt_name\n"
        . "\n"
        . "Message.\n"
        . "\n"
        . "\n"
        . "Click Here To Unsubscribe.";

        @mail($opt_email_to, $opt_subject ,$opt_message ,$opt_header) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. The opt_name is meant to be the name of the email who is sending the email.

Comment: Sorry, I was just focusing on the mysql part. Try the edited version now. Though I am confused why the sender and the receiver's name is same in `Hey $opt_name\n`

Comment: That didn't work as well unfortunately. I think I should just use AWeber fix everything. Thank you for your time and help.